# SQL Server 2005 and 2008 in conjunction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is it recommended to use two versions of SQL Server (2005 and 2008) for storing data of an application. We have a situation where we have an existing web application consuming SQL server 2005 as a database. Some enhancements in the application required us to solution a FILESTREAM data store. Now we have our data in SQL Server 2005 and associated FILESTREAM data in SQL Server 2008. Being very new to SQL Server I would like to ascertain how bad is this in terms of performance? How can we achieve atomicity across both the database versions, is it via using a linked server or some other mechanism? Any alternative solutions would be fine except that we just cannot migrate the existing application to SQL Server 2008.

Comment: If you cannot migrate the application to SQL Server 2008, would it be an option to migrate the database to SQL Server 2005 instead?

Comment: @Timwi - SQL Server 2005 doesn't support `FILESTREAM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep your transactions ACID, you can use [distributed transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213066(SQL.80).aspx) at a stored procedure level, or from a code level using DTC (e.g. via a .net TransactionScope). DTC would need to be present on both SQL Servers, and on your App Server as well if you do the ACID from there. There is some overhead with DTC

Edit : You will also need to link the servers with [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479(SQL.100).aspx) and provide credentials with sp_addlinkedsrvlogin

Comment: Is it necessary to link the servers for using .NET Transaction scope?

Comment: Hi MSDN Expert - No, with DTC and TransactionScope across the 2 servers you wouldn't need to link the servers - DTC will coordinate the 2 connections independently - whereas a solution with a SQL BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION would require the linked servers. Apologies for not being more clear on this.